# Throw error from dataTask completionHandler

Tags: swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

In swift how do I throw an error within a completion handler like this:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        do {
            //something
            completion(result)
        } catch let jsonError {
            throw CustomError.myerror //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

as the error is

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws ->
>   ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) ->
>   Void'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get throws to work with function with completion handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402348/cant-get-throws-to-work-with-function-with-completion-handler)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short story: You can't `throw` in a `dataTask` completion closure

You could return two values in the completion handler

```
...completion: @escaping (ResultType?, Error?)->Void
```

and return

```
completion(result, nil)
completion(nil, CustomError.myerror)
```

or more convenient use an enum with associated type

```
enum Result {
    case success(ResultType), failure(Error)
}

...completion: @escaping (Result)->Void
```

and return

```
completion(.success(result))
completion(.failure(CustomError.myerror))
```

You can process the result

```
foo() { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let resultType): // do something with the result
    case .failure(let error): // Handle the error
    }
}
```

Update:

In Swift 5 using the new built-in `Result` type it's even more comfortable because `Result` can capture the result of the throwing expression

```
...completion: @escaping (Result<MyType,Error>)->Void

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    completion(Result { try something()})
})
task.resume()
```

Update 2:

With `async/await` completion handlers are gone

```
do {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
} catch {
     throw CustomError.myerror
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I used the latter option. How do I check the type of result, like if the result is of type .success or .failure

Comment: @vadian, I'm not sure I follow how the code you've suggested gets around the type signature for the dataTask - `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`

Would you be able to post how you take this code - https://pastecode.xyz/view/de5fe2cc, and get it to return the enum like you mentioned?